# GoTo "Expected Statement"

Tags: vbscript, compiler-errors

I am attempting to use the `GoTo` command (I do not know any alternatives and it works fine in batch). Whenever I attempt to load the program, I get this error:

[image: error screenshot]

Here is basically where the error is (line 11 column 3)

```
top:
input = InputBox("Enter normal text:", "Message Encrypt Style 2", "Text goes here")
If input = "" Then
    Y = MsgBox("You inputed nothing!", vbRetryCancel+64, "Huh?")
    If Y = 2 Then
        WScript.Quit
    Else
        If Y = 4 Then
            GoTo top
        Else
            If input = 2 Then
                WScript.Quit
```

Comment: You can't use labels in `vbscript`.  That's why you are getting the error.  What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB GoTo failing compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107723/vb-goto-failing-compilation)

Comment: @Lankymart: That question is specifically about `On Error Goto`. I think this is a different question about `Goto` by itself, though of course it has the same answer (that `Goto` doesn't exist in VBScript).

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. exactly, the answer is the same. If the question was more generic it would suit both variations. No excuse for dup questions though.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript doesn't have a `Goto` statement, and there's a cleaner approach anyway.

```
Do
    input = InputBox(...)

    If IsEmpty(input) Or input = "2" Then
        WScript.Quit
    ElseIf input = "" Then
        MsgBox "No input."
    End If
Loop Until input <> ""
```

Comment: Same error, on the `Until input <> ""` line. I can include the whole code if necessary.

Comment: My bad. There was a `Loop` missing before the `Until`. Fixed.

Comment: Error: 'loop' without 'do'

Comment: Code: 800A040E.

Comment: You wrote `Else If` instead of `ElseIf`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Dim Input ' as string
Dim Y ' as msgbox response

Input = ""

Do Until Input <> ""
    Input= InputBox("Enter normal text:", "Message Encrypt Style 2", "Text goes here")

    If Input = "" Then
        Y = Msgbox ("You input nothing", vbRetryCancel, "Huh?")
        If Y = vbCancel Then
            WScript.Quit
        End If
    ElseIf Input = "2" Then
        WScript.Quit
    End If  
Loop

' Proceed here if input is valid
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that in my next program!

Answer (score 0):

Vbscript is a structured programming language and one of the main goals of structured programming is to eliminate the `goto` statement as it's [considered harmful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful).  Vbscript does have a `goto` for exceptions, but these are only meant for resource cleanup prior to a program exit.